# Splitting and looping over live command output in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am archiving and using `split` to produce several parts while also printing the output files (from `split` on STDERR, which I am redirecting to STDOUT). However the loop over the output data doesn't happen until after the command returns.

Is there anyway to actively split over the STDOUT output of a command before it returns?

The following is what I currently have, but it only prints the list of filenames after the command returns:

```
export IFS=$'\n'
for line in `data_producing_command | split -d -b $CHUNK_SIZE --verbose - $ARCHIVE_PREFIX 2>&1`; do
    FILENAME=`echo $line | awk '{ print $3 }'`
    echo "    - $FILENAME"
done
```

Comment: Can you add current and expected output? or perhaps rephrase the question. Didn't get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am asking how to actively split and print the output of a command that is continually printing to STDOUT. What I provide only prints after the command finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data_producing_command | split -d -b $CHUNK_SIZE --verbose - $ARCHIVE_PREFIX 2>&1 | while read -r line
do
    FILENAME=`echo $line | awk '{ print $3 }'`
    echo "    - $FILENAME"
done
```

Note however that any variables set in the `while` loop will not preserve their values after the loop (the `while` loop runs in a subshell).

Comment: You can pipe to `for` too: `cat aFileToMakeStdout |for n in $(cat -) ; do echo $n ;done`

Comment: @Leon No change. What's the difference in function between looping over implicit execution and calling "read"?

Comment: @LinuxDisciple That's essentially what I had.

Comment: @DustinOprea During command substitution (when calling a command between backticks or better using the recommended syntax `$(command)`) the command must complete before its full output is expanded into the shell script. In a pipe members of the pipe can be executed in parallel.

Comment: @Leon Although that's an exceptional point, I did try both (as well as then trying your method). That's why it's odd that it didn't work.

Comment: @DustinOprea In a pipe `cmd1|cmd2`, `cmd2` will be executed "in parallel" with `cmd1` if the output of `cmd1` is large enough. Otherwise, small output of `cmd1` may be buffered and flushed only after it completes.

Comment: @DustinOprea Note that there is a way to disable pipe buffering: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the for loop or the read or the echo. Just pipe the stream to awk:

```
... | split -d -b $CHUNK_SIZE --verbose - test 2>&1 |
 awk '{printf "    - %s\n", $3 }'
```

You are going to see some delay from buffering, but unless your system is very slow or you are very perceptive, you're not likely to notice it.

Answer (score 0):

The command substitution needs<sup>1</sup> to run before the `for` loop can start.

```
for item in $(command which produces items); do ...
```

whereas a `while read -r` can start consuming output as soon as the first line is produced (or, more realistically, as soon as the output buffer is full):

```
command which produces items |
while read -r item; do ...
```

<sup>1</sup> Well, it doesn't absolutely *need* to, from a design point of view, I suppose, but that's how it currently works.

As William Pursell already noted, there is no particular reason to run Awk inside a `while read` loop, because that's something Awk does quite well on its own, actually.

```
command which produces items |
awk '{ print "    - " $3 }'
```

Of course, with a reasonably recent GNU Coreutils `split`, you could simply do

```
split --filter='printf "   - %s\n" "$FILE"'; cat >"$FILE" ... options
```